# How to generate random string?

Tags: python, random

I just want to ask that like taking random number from: `Random.randint(a, b)`

I just want to ask that how to take random string just like `randint` but this time with random string. Is there anyway?

```
#This program will play a little game

import random

a = ''
b = ''
c = ''
d = ''
e = ''
f = ''

print('Hi. Please enter your name in letters')
name = str(input())
print('Hi ' + name + '. I am going to play a little game. In this game you have to guess a specific name i am thinking right now.')
print('But do not worry. I am going to let you to enter 6 names and i will choose one of them.')
print('After that you have to answer the correct name that i am thinking right now')
print('Please enter the first name in letters')
name1 = str(input())
print('Please enter the second name in letters')
name2 = str(input())
print('Please enter the third name in letters')
name3 = str(input())
print('Please enter the fourth name in letters')
name4 = str(input())
print('Please enter the fifth name in letters')
name5 = str(input())
print('Please enter the sixth name in letters')
name6 = str(input())
name1 = a
name2 = b
name3 = c
name4 = d
name5 = e
name6 = f

print('Alright ' + name + ' . Thank you for entering the names.')
secretname = random.randint(a, f)
for i in range(2):
        print('Now enter the name that i am thinking of.')
        ans = str(input())
        if ans != secretname:
                print('Wrong. Guess another name')

if ans == secretname:
        print('Good job ' + name)
else:
        print('Wrong. The name i was thinking of was ' + secretname)
```

This is a little game which request from you to enter 6 names and then the game will guess a number between those 6 numbers you have entered but it always gaves me an error.  want to do it with random string.

## My Working Version

```
import random

print('Hi. Please enter your name in letters')
yourname = str(input())
print('Hi ' + yourname + '. I am going to play a little game. In this game you have to guess a specific name i am thinking right now.\nBut do not worry. I am going to let you to enter 6 names and i will choose one of them.\nAfter that you have to answer the correct name that i am thinking right now\nPlease enter the first name in letters')

name = ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
number = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]


def insert(n):
    temp = name.copy()
    name[n] = str(input("name " + str(n + 1) + ": "))
    if name[n] in temp:
        print("[error]: ---> This name exists yet, try again")
        print(">>>", end='')
        insert(n)

for n in range(6):
    insert(n)
    print('Please enter the ' + number[n] + ' name in letters')

print('Alright ' + yourname + ' . Thank you for entering the names.')
secretname = name[random.randint(0, 6)]
print("Soluzion: ", secretname)
print("-" * 10)
for i in range(2):
    print('Now enter the name that i am thinking of.')
    ans = str(input())
    if ans != secretname:
        print('Wrong. Guess another name')

if ans == secretname:
    print('Good job ' + yourname)
else:
    print('Wrong. The name i was thinking of was ' + secretname)
```

Output

> ```
> Hi. Please enter your name in letters Gio Hi Gio. I am going to play a
> little game. In this game you have to guess a specific name i am
> thinking right now. But do not worry. I am going to let you to enter 6
> names and i will choose one of them. After that you have to answer the
> correct name that i am thinking right now Please enter the first name
> in letters 
> name 0: Giovanni
> Please enter the first name in letters
> name 1: Marta
> Please enter the second name in letters
> name 2: Giovanni
> [error]: ---> This name exists yet, try again
> >>>name 2: Giovanni
> [error]: ---> This name exists yet, try again
> >>>name 2: Carlo
> Please enter the third name in letters 
> name 3: Mimmo Please enter the fourth name in letters 
> name 4: June
> Please enter the fifth name in letters
> name 5: Caterina Please enter the sixth name in letters
> Alright Gio . Thank you for entering the names.
> Solution: Mimmo
> ----------
> Now enter the name that i am thinking of.
> M 
> Wrong. Guess another name Now enter the name that i am thinking of.
> Mimmo 
> Good job Gio
> ```

Comment: There are many problems in your code... no need to use `str` around `input()`, your name variables are being deleted right after the input by doing `name1=a` etc... you are not using `random.randint` right at all.... I suggest you attempt smaller pieces to see if they even work before joining them all to a program. If you have specific questions free free to open more detailed question about the actual errors, but with *minimal* examples

Answer (score 7):

```
import string
import random
def random_string(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for m in xrange(length))

print random_string(10)
print random_string(5)
```

**Output:**

```
'oJyPiEbhka'
'XXwuA'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using random.randint :

```
my_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
index = random.randint(0,25)
letter = my_string[index]
```

You  just have to loop over that to build strings from letters

Answer (score 1):

**Hello M. Husnain,**

## Chr() Function

**chr(i)**
Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while chr(8364) returns the string '€'. This is the inverse of ord().

The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

## Solution

Try this below code,

```
#This program will play a little game

import random

a = ''
b = ''
c = ''
d = ''
e = ''
f = ''

print('Hi. Please enter your name in letters')
name = raw_input()


print('Hi ' + name + '. I am going to play a little game. In this game you have to guess a specific name i am thinking right now.')
print('But do not worry. I am going to let you to enter 6 names and i will choose one of them.')
print('After that you have to answer the correct name that i am thinking right now')
print('Please enter the first name in letters')
name1 = raw_input()

print('Please enter the second name in letters')
name2 = raw_input()

print('Please enter the third name in letters')
name3 = raw_input()

print('Please enter the fourth name in letters')
name4 = raw_input()

print('Please enter the fifth name in letters')
name5 = raw_input()

print('Please enter the sixth name in letters')
name6 = raw_input()

print('Alright ' + name + ' . Thank you for entering the names.')

lists1 = [name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6]

secretname = lists1[random.randint(0,len(lists1))]

for i in range(2):
        print('Now enter the name that i am thinking of.')
        ans = raw_input()
        if ans != secretname:
                print('Wrong. Guess another name')

if ans == secretname:
     print('Good job ' + name)
else:
    print('Wrong. The name i was thinking of was ' + secretname)
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import string
alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
''.join(random.choice(alpha + num) for _ in range(5)) #number you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the names into different variables I'd propose a list containing the names entered. It could look something like this:

```
name_list = []
print('Please enter the first name in letters')
name_list.append(input())
print('Please enter the second name in letters')
name_list.append(input())
...
```

You can then randomly select a list item using [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) e.g.

```
import random
secretname = random.choice(name_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

For the specific case you described, you can simply create a list of characters containing all of the characters you allow. then you can use this, to create a word of length `X` (replace with actual length:

```
base_chars = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3' ]
word_length = 10 #change this to the desired word length
[random.choice(base_chars) for _ in range(word_length)]
```

## Original:

#### Random string - define your characters

You should first decide what kind of characters you want to use.
For example, if you want to use ASCII chars from 0 to 127 or maybe just a-z and A-Z. Also consider digits, space etc. So you should first decide the set of characters you want to select randomly from.

#### Selecting a character randomly

If you would like to use 0 to 127 range in the ASCII table, you can use this:

`char = chr(random.randint(0, 127))`

#### Generating a random word

Now, to create a word, you should first decide the size of it. This can also be randomize. For example, we will randomly choose a size of a word (with limited range):

```
rand_str = ""
for _ in range(10):
     rand_str += chr(random.randint(0, 127))
```